# After catching some error with my node app I am not understanding the error message

Tags: node.js

When I'm catching the exception and am trying to print the stack trace it outputs `undefined`

`console.log(err.stack);`  => `undefined`

And when i print the error on console it says
The error occured is :

```
function next(err) {
    if (err && err === 'route') {
    return done();
  }

  var layer = stack[idx++];
  if (!layer) {
    return done(err);
  }

  if (layer.method && layer.method !== method) {
    return next(err);
  }

  if (err) {
    layer.handle_error(err, req, res, next);
  } else {
    layer.handle_request(req, res, next);
  }
}
```

`
What does this exception (error) message means?

Answer (score 0):

What you've called `err` in your code is not actually a JavaScript error. It is in fact the `next` function which is passed as the third argument to routing/middleware functions in express.

The code that you logged out is the function body that can be found here: https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/f73ff9243006ea010fffdaa748f06df3a5b986e7/lib/router/route.js#L114-L133.

Can you post the code where you're handling and logging the error?

Comment: The third argument to your routing functions isn't `err` as you've named it, it should be `next` and it's a function. Calling the `next` function calls the next handler in the routing chain and calling it with an error object causes a central error handler to be called.

Express routes themselves don't have 'errors' as you have in your code. Have a look at the [Express routing guide](http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html) to find out more about routing functions.